# SSH key not working on git bash after closing and opening new

Tags: git, github

Have create ssh key using following link
(https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)
Once create ssh key using git bash and added to github. It works only for that particular git bash. If I close git bash and open again. Same ssh key wont work, need to create new. CAn anyone please tell me why is it happening? or what is missing?

Comment: 1. Which OS are you using? I suppose windows, right?
2. Did you run the command `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` right before everything worked for you?
3. Did you try running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` after you reopen git bash and before you tried to call other commands?

Comment: Please note that the page https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent recommends to start `ssh-agent` using command `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` which is neither secure nor recommended in general. In order to get familiar with `ssh-agent` I would propose you to read these articles: 1 - http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents , 2 - https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch02_05.htm .

Answer (score 9):

You would need to auto add the ssh key to every session when you open Git Bash. For that, if you are on Windows, follow the below steps :

- Go to the location of Git installation (usually at `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh`)
- Edit the `ssh_config` file and add the line `IdentityFile Drive:\path\to\key` where `Drive:\path\to\key` should specify the local path to your key that you have generated earlier, and save the file after editing.

Now every time you open Git Bash, the key would automatically be added to the ssh session and you will not need to add the ssh key everytime.

Comment: Solved vsc issues for me. Thanks!

Comment: This will work if you have admin access.

Answer (score 4):

No matter what operating system version you run you need to run this command to complete setup:

`$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: 1. Could you please explain your answer?
2. I was unable to find the key `-K` (uppercase) in `ssh-add` manual. Did you mean `-k` (lowercase)?

Comment: No its uppercase K. Here's what `man ssh-add` shows me
`-K:      When adding identities, each passphrase will also be stored in the user's keychain.`

Comment: -K is an unknown parameter for me too

Comment: This may be dependent on the OS and ssh version, here's what I have:
`➜  ~ sw_vers
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.2
BuildVersion: 19C57
➜  ~ /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.ssh/config` file, add:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps if you have to add the key each time you start a new bash session.

1. After generating the key and adding it to the .ssh/ folder(if you have doubt in generating the public and private keys you can refer to this link from git documentation [[key-gen]](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)).
2. The Bash profile is a file on your computer that Bash runs every time a new Bash session is created hence you can start and add the key everytime by using this bash profile in your system.
3. Edit .bash_profile of your git bash using the below script. Add this to your .bash_profile

```
    #!/bin/bash
    eval `ssh-agent -s`
    a=$?
    if [ $a == 0 ]
    then
        ssh-add ~/.ssh/"<yoursshkeyfile>"
        b=$?
        if [ $b == 0 ]
        then
            echo "------------------key added-----------------"
        else
            echo "--------------key not added but agent started----------"
        fi
    else
        echo "----------------agent not started---------------"
    fi
```

This basically starts and adds your key everytime you open the bash.
`eval ssh-agent -s` starts the agent and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/"<yoursshkeyfile>"` (add the private key file and not the public) adds your key present in ./ssh directory. "$?" this is just to check the exit status of the command executed before. This returns 0 if executed without error.